# Which one is BIG

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

Let we have two event :

> Event A: **$ab^3$**
>
> Event B: **$a^3b$**

The range of a and b are given as: $-1 < a <0 < |a|< b< 1$

It seems to me a big range to test that which event is big. How to do this quickly without putting lots of numbers to testify?

Comment: Please check the answer which one is bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A = $ab(b^2)$

B = $ab(a^2)$

Because $-1<a<0<b<1$,　$ab<0$.

Because $|a|<b$,　$a^2<b^2$.

Therefore, $ab^3<a^3b$.

Comment: So the event B is greater?

Comment: Sorry, From b^2>a^2, Because ab<$0$, A=ab(b^2)<B=ab(a^2). So event B is greater.

Comment: But $b^> a^2$ so , why not, $ab^3>a^3b$?

Comment: If the larger the absolute value of a negative number, the value is smaller.